# How to write a python code to append data to json list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a python script which will have user input to enter a word and its definitions (multiple definitions) and append them to a JSON file

For some word there will be only one definition but others might have multiple ones.

#### JSON Example:

```
{'acid': ['A compound capable of transferring a hydrogen ion in solution.',
          'Being harsh or corrosive in tone.',
          'Having an acid, sharp or tangy taste.',
          'A powerful hallucinogenic drug manufactured from lysergic acid.',
          'Having a pH less than 7, or being sour, or having the strength to '
          'neutralize  alkalis, or turning a litmus paper red.'],
 'acoustic filter': ['A device employed to reject sound in a particular range '
                     'of frequencies while passing sound in another range of '
                     'frequencies.'],
 'acoustic insulation': ['The process of preventing the transmission of sound '
                         'by surrounding with a nonconducting material.']}
```

#### Code:

```
import json

while True:
    Word = input('Enter Word:')
    Definition1 = input('Definition 1: ')
    Definition2 = input('Definition 2: ')
    Definition3 = input('Definition 3: ')
    Definition4 = input('Definition 4: ')
    Definition5 = input('Definition 5: ')
    Definition6 = input('Definition 6: ')

with open("files/data.json", "r+") as data:
    information = {Word, Definition1, Definition2, Definition3, Definition4, Definition5}
    data.write(json.dumps(information))
    data.close()
```

Comment: updated formatting for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I would advice the structure like this:

```
import json

words_dict = {}
while True:
    tmp_list_of_definitions = []
    word = input('Enter Word:')

    if word in words_dict:
        print('You already entered definitions for such word!')
        answer = input('Is the procedure over? [y/n]')
        if answer == 'y':
            break
        continue     

    def_counter = 0

    print('In case you want to stop entering the definitions print "stop"')
    while True:
        definition = input('Definition {}: '.format(def_counter))
        def_counter += 1
        if definition == 'stop':
            break
        tmp_list_of_definitions.append(definition)
    words_dict[word] = tmp_list_of_definitions
    answer = input('Is the procedure over? [y/n]')
    if answer == 'y':
        break
```

And you don't have to use *close* when using *with open()*.

Comment: Thanks @j.smith i had below issues though.

Comment: Thanks @j.smith i had below issues though.
but below two issues are there
1) The 'Word' does'nt get append to the json file
2) every time I run the script the words_dict  keep overriding istead of appending or adding to the existing data in json file

Expected result

{"apple": ["A native Eurasian tree of the genus ''Malus''.", "The popular, crisp, round fruit of the apple tree, usually with red, yellow or green skin, light-coloured flesh and pips inside.", "The wood of the apple tree."]}


Testing Done here:  https://repl.it/@TinoAugustine/WrongWiseEngines

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    information = dict()

    while True:
         key = input("Enter word or 'q' to quit:")
         if key is 'q':
             break
         definition_list = list()
        while True:
            definition = input("Enter definition or 'n' to next word:")
            if definition is 'n':
                break
            definition_list.append(definition)
        information[key] = definition_list

    with open("data.json", "r+") as data:
        data.write(json.dumps(information))

exit(0)
```